# Need help Toggle Button in AJAx in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, togglebutton

I want the page to be updated each time the checkbox is checked or unchecked (which is using the Toggle Button from AJAX). But I am not able to do so. I tried doing the same with a button and an imagebutton, they work great( but i faced problem when I tried to update the toggle button in the "onclick" function), but I want to do this with the toggle button, I tried various means by using Page_Load() in  databinding and checkchanged events but in vain. How can I correct the code>

Also I want to resize my background according to the resolution of the user. How can I do so? I surfed the net and tried to do many things with a stylesheet but in vain. Please Help.

The Codes are given below from Vidual Studio 9.

**Default.aspx :**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Confidentially for 'You'</title>
     <link id="Link1" rel="Stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" runat="server" />
</head>
<body background="eternal_hearts-normal.jpg" text="white">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate> 
    <p align="center" runat="server" id="p1">
        <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />Default Line</p>
            <p align="center" id="p2">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                    oncheckedchanged="Page_Load" ondatabinding="Page_Load" />

                <cc1:ToggleButtonExtender ID="CheckBox1_ToggleButtonExtender" runat="server" 
                    Enabled="True" TargetControlID="CheckBox1" ImageWidth="19" 
                    ImageHeight="19" UncheckedImageUrl="ToggleButton_Unchecked.gif" 
                    CheckedImageUrl="ToggleButton_Checked.gif" ondatabinding="Page_Load">
                </cc1:ToggleButtonExtender>

                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="23px" 
                    onclick="ImageButton1_Click" Width="30px" 
                    ImageUrl="~/ToggleButton_Unchecked.gif" />
                &nbsp;</p>
     </ContentTemplate> 
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs :**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Threading;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    static int flag = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            f();
            p1.InnerHtml = "Line 1";
        }
        else if (flag == 2)
        {
            f();
            p1.InnerHtml = "Line 2";
        }
        else if (flag == 3)
        {
            f();
            p1.InnerHtml = "Line 3";
        }
        flag++;
    }
    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (flag == 0)
        //{
        //    flag++;
        //    p1.InnerHtml = "Line 1";
        //}
        //else if (flag == 1)
        //{
        //    flag++;
        //    p1.InnerHtml = "Line 2";
        //}
        //else if (flag == 2)
        //{
        //    flag++;
        //    p1.InnerHtml = "Line 3";
        //}

    }

    protected void f()
    {
        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "ToggleButton_Unchecked.gif";
    }
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

**Stylesheet :**

```css
img#background 
{
    min-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

div.back
{
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -9999;
}

body
{
    text-align: center;
    left: 50pt;
    right: 50pt;
    font-family: 'Bookman Old Style';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: auto;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi. You need to remove the Classic ASP tag from your question. Your example does not show any Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

A little late in answer but try this -> http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ToggleButton/ToggleButton.aspx